# How can I launch the native file choosers for both mac and windows?

Tags: java, file, native, filechooser

I want to launch the native file chooser for mac and windows, respectively. I saw a previous answer that uses UIManager to setLookandFeel() to system defaults, but it only imitates the native chooser. Is there a way to launch the actual native file chooser? [Here is what I want to see when I run on Macs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXvX6.png) and [here it is for Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyzSD.png)